# Trying to prevent exceptions in c# (no overload for method 'TryParse'

Tags: c#

I am currently making a simple menu for a c# console application.. I am trying to prevent exceptions when letters are typed instead of numbers.   Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. thanks

```
        userSelection = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()); 

        switch(userSelection)
        {   
        case 1:
            readFile();
            validAnswer = true;
            break;

        case 2:
            decryption();
            validAnswer = true;
            break;

        case 3:
            validAnswer = true;
            Environment.Exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Your selection is invalid. Please try  again.");
            Console.ResetColor();
            break;
        }

    }while (!validAnswer);
}
```

Comment: `TryParse` requires an `out` argument.  You should [read the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This is not an exception, but compiler error. Just read the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
userSelection = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Should be:

```
bool isNumber = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userSelection);
```

TryParse takes two arguments, first is the string to convert, second is where to put the result of the conversion (which needs to be marked `out`), and it returns a boolean if the conversion succeeded.

In order to make your switch work, you could do something like this:

```
bool isNumber = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userSelection);

if (!isNumber)
    userSelection = -1;
```

Which will drive your `switch` into the `default` case and say that the number input was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to a bool variable which will say if the operation succeeded or not.

```
int userSelection = -1;
bool res = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userSelection);
if (res == false)
{
    // String is not a number.
}
else 
{
 //proceed
}
```